# I create project using nextjs.org learn part, I have problem with authentication

Tags: authentication, next.js, next-auth

have a problem with authentication, after signIn it does not redirect me to my dashboard.
All files I step by step copy from nextjs.org.

This is auth.config.ts file

```
import type { NextAuthConfig } from 'next-auth';
 
export const authConfig = {
  pages: {
    signIn: '/login',
  },
  callbacks: {
    authorized({ auth, request }) {
      const isLoggedIn = !!auth?.user;
      
      const isOnDashboard = request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/ui/dashboard');
      if (isOnDashboard) {
        if (isLoggedIn) return true;
        return false; // Redirect unauthenticated users to login page
      } else if (isLoggedIn) {
        return Response.redirect(new URL('/ui/dashboard/invoices', request.nextUrl));
      }
      return true;
    },
  },
  providers: [], // Add providers with an empty array for now
} satisfies NextAuthConfig;
```

When I logged in, I have to redirect to the dashboard page, but it's not redirected.
I think the problem comes from auth.config.ts,
I always console.log the value of   **isLoggedIn** and it  always is null.
It doesn't matter user is signIn or signOut.

The login proccess is paritally work, I check it using this auth() function, from auth.ts

```
export const { auth, signIn, handlers: {POST, GET}, signOut } = NextAuth({...
```